# return index of matching value over columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**my input:**

```
task1 = pd.DataFrame({'task1':  ['|ReviewNG-Cecum Landmark','|ReviewNG-Cecum Landmark','|Cecum Landmark','|Cecum Landmark','|Cecum Landmark','|Cecum Landmark','|ReviewNG-Cecum Landmark',
'|ReviewNG-Cecum Landmark','|Other','|Other','|Other']})
task2 = pd.DataFrame({'task2': ['|Cecum Landmark|Other','|Cecum Landmark|Other','|Cecum Landmark|Other','|Cecum Landmark|Other','|Other','|Other','|Other',
'|Other']})
df = pd.concat([task1, task2], join = 'outer', axis = 1)
```

I trying get over `df` all range where matching value is `true`.
**My code:**

```
pat = "\|Cecum Landmark\||\|Cecum Landmark"
idx = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(pat, regex=True),axis=1)
idx.index[idx['task1']== True].tolist()
```

**What I get:***

> [2, 3, 4, 5]

So its correct, but how to get all index over each column in df? In other word, I dont want input manually name of column to get index matching value, but get ouptut per column.
**So what I expect:**

> [2,3,4,5]
> [0,1,2,3]

so for example two lists(or more) each for its own column. There might be a better way to find matches and get the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,

```
result = df.apply(
    lambda x: x.index[x.str.contains(pat, regex=True, na=False)].tolist(),
    axis=0,
    result_type="reduce",
).tolist()
```